# Designing methods for manipulating arraylist in java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm creating an ArrayList of objects in main and need to create separate public methods for various manipulations with them from outside the main.
But such methods can't see my ArrayList. For instance, if the object is a Person with some fields, like name and I need a separate method to access the list of Persons, iterate through it, see if a person with this name already exists to change or retrieve the name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    Person person1 = new Person("Daniel");
    personList.add(person1);
            
}
public boolean changeName(String name) {
    //how to reach the list to iterate and manipulate it from here?     
return true;
    
}
```

Comment: You can either change the scope of your ArrayList from a local variable to a field, or you pass it into the methods as an argument.

Comment: Only because _design_ is part of the question:  directly exposing and passing around a data structure is a bit smelly in the context of your question.  Consider creating a class, such as `People`, that encapsulates  the list.  The class would provide methods, such as `changeName(...)`, and the People object is passed around (rather than the naked data structure).

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the list outside of main method making it global to the class like this:

```
public class Main{

     //making your list accessible to other methods within the class
     static ArrayList<Person> personList;
     public static void main(String[] args){
         personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
         Person person1 = new Person("Daniel");
         personList.add(person1);
     }
     //Your methods ...
     // ...
}
```

Also you can pass in the list to the parameters of the method:

```
public static void addPerson(ArrayList<Person> list, Person person){
    list.add(person);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But don't these methods of exposing the list disrupt encapsulation?

Comment: As written, you've declared `personList` as an instance member of class `Main`. Your `main()` method is static, though, which it should be. But since `main()` is static, it cannot reference the instance member `personList`. Static methods can only access other static methods and static members. The opposite is not true, though. Instance methods can access both instance and static members.

Comment: @rainbow hmm... what do you mean by disrupting encapsulation? Everything is fine within the Person class... Concerning the class where main method is in, if you are afraid that other classes can access the "personList", you can declare it private, although by default "personList" is accessible only within the classes of the same package("folder")

Comment: @Idle_Mind , yeah that makes sense, forgot to add static keyword to the field